# Adding Self Signed Certificate to trusted root certificate store using Command Line

Tags: ssl, iis, trusted-root-certificates

Is there any way to add certificate to Local Computer's Trusted Root Certification Authority using command line? I tried using certmgr.exe, it shows success but when i check root CA, i don't see my certificate there.

I followed the guide here:

```
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172241.aspx
```

Basically trying this command:

```
certmgr.exe -add -c mycertificate.cer -s -r localMachine root
```

The command works and shows success on command line, but i can not see the certificate in actual trusted root store through mmc, Is it the procedure for self signed certificate is different?
I have setup an IIS server with SSL Binding to this certificate which is originally placed in "MY" store. But im doing everything through autoamted scripts so i want to know how can i add this certificate to trusted root CA using cmd line option??

Comment: What were the actual command line options you used with CertMgr.exe?  What (user) context is are the scripts running in?  How did you create the certificate?  How are you checking the root CA?

Comment: i used only this command: certmgr.exe -add -c mycertificate.cer -s -r localMachine root

Comment: and off course the script is a invoked java process running under admin privileges.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try it manually (by double-clicking on the CER file)? If even manually it's not working, you might be encountering [a Vista bug](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;932156).

### Install a Root CA certificate from the command line (cmd.exe)

(This requires the Windows SDK. Visual Studio will install it for you and add it to the `%PATH%`.)

`certmgr /add /c mycertificate.cer /s /r localMachine root`

Note that no errors will be reported; the command will always return success (even when using a non-existing file for the certificate!). If the certificate doesn't show up in the Certificate Manager (`certmgr.msc`) after running this command, repeat the process using the manual steps below to check if there is any error in your certificate file.

### Manual steps to install a Root CA certificate

1. Double-click on the `.cer` file.
2. On the *Certificate* dialog box, click *Install Certificate* to start
   the *Certificate Import Wizard*.
3. On the *Welcome* page, click *Next*.
4. On the *Certificate Store* page, select *Place all certificates in the
   following store* and click *Browse*.
5. In the *Select Certificate Store* dialog box, select *Show Physical
   Stores*.
6. Double-click *Trusted Root Certification Authorities*, select *Local
   Computer*, and then click *OK*.
7. On the *Certificate Store* page, click *Next*.
8. On the summary page, review the details and click *Finish*.

### Install a Root CA certificate from PowerShell

See @harrymc's great answer below.

Comment: Thank you, actually yes the problem was with certificate itself as i tried with other certificates and it worked.

Comment: the OP mentions using command line

Comment: @JoãoPimentelFerreira: The OP's command line is fine, the certificate was buggy (see OP's comment above yours). But his use case is narrower than your bounty's.

Answer (score 4):

The PowerShell command
[Import-Certificate](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/pkiclient/import-certificate?view=win10-ps)
can be used to import a certificate:

```
Import-Certificate -FilePath "C:\path\Cert.Cer" -CertStoreLocation cert:\CurrentUser\Root
```

To run it through the Command Prompt (or batch) you may run it as:

```
powershell "Import-Certificate -FilePath ^"C:\path\Cert.Cer^" -CertStoreLocation cert:\CurrentUser\Root"
```

Note above the use of the `^` escape character.

To list all available certificate stores, start a PowerShell session and enter:

```
dir cert:\\LocalMachine\
```

Comment: does this solution avoid warnings on the browsers?

Comment: What kind of warnings? There shouldn't be any if the certificate is there.

Comment: sometimes I install the certificates like that, but browsers still present security warnings. https://bytebitebit.com/1124/disable-invalid-ssl-certificate-warning/

Comment: @JoãoPimentelFerreira: If you mean the invalid SSL certificate warning, why is it invalid? Problems like elapsed date can be worked around in some browsers but not all. Missing Root Certification Authority is much more serious. So which is it?

Comment: how can I give you the bounty? It's quite odd. The first time I'm doing this because I created the bounty but I am not the OP. Stack Exchange rules are quite complex with all these time limits and restrictions.

Comment: @JoãoPimentelFerreira: Too late - your bounty has elapsed; it only lasts 7+1 days. Don't worry about it.

Comment: but if remember correctly when I am the OP and the bounty creator, I can still attribute the bounty after that time period. It's unfair for you.

Comment: It sometimes happens. No problem on my side.

Answer (score 0):

Powershell "Import-Certificate -FilePath 'C:\path\Cert.Cer' -CertStoreLocation Cert:\LocalMachine\Root"

The path location needs to have the ' rather than the " for cmd